# working with 2 combox populated from one data collection

Tags: c#

I am fairy new in C# and trying to learn it .
I need to have a dialogBox to transfer money from one account to another accounts, all accounts belong to one specific customer,so I have decided to define customer's accountCollection as a static variable of customer class. in the dialog box there are 2 combo boxes that one of them holds from account and the other one holds to account. I populated them using DataSourse member. But the problem here is whatever account I select from one combo box the same account is selected in the other combobox. I do not know how to fix it . If anyone can give me some hints it is really appreciated.
here is my work :

```
public partial class TransferDialog : Form
{
    string enteredAmount;
    int fromComboBoxSelectedIndex;
    int toComboBoxSelectedIndex;



    public TransferDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TransferDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pupulateComboBox();
        comboBoxFromAccountTransferDialog.DisplayMember = "AccountName";
        comboBoxToAccountTransferDialog.DisplayMember = "AccountName";
    }

    private void pupulateComboBox()
    {
        AccountCollection accountsForFromComboBox = new AccountCollection();
        AccountCollection accountsForToComboBox = new AccountCollection();
        accountsForFromComboBox = Customer.Accounts;
        accountsForToComboBox = Customer.Accounts;
        comboBoxFromAccountTransferDialog.DataSource = accountsForFromComboBox;
        comboBoxToAccountTransferDialog.DataSource = accountsForToComboBox;
    }

    private void buttonOkTranserFundDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fromComboBoxSelectedIndex = comboBoxFromAccountTransferDialog.SelectedIndex;
        toComboBoxSelectedIndex = comboBoxToAccountTransferDialog.SelectedIndex;
        enteredAmount = textBoxTransferAmont.Text;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; 
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there any property to identify an account? is that the `AccountName`?

Comment: BTW, I can see that 2 comboboxes have the same source `Customer.Accounts` so they should always have the same selected item.

Answer (score 0):

You initially define two separate lists.

```
AccountCollection accountsForFromComboBox = new AccountCollection();
AccountCollection accountsForToComboBox = new AccountCollection();
```

But then you point them both to the same `Customer.Accounts` collection. So now they're referencing the same object.

```
accountsForFromComboBox = Customer.Accounts;
accountsForToComboBox = Customer.Accounts;
```

Then you set the datasources on the two combo boxes, which are also both referencing the same `Customer.Accounts` collection. You need to keep them separate from one another.

```
comboBoxFromAccountTransferDialog.DataSource = accountsForFromComboBox;
comboBoxToAccountTransferDialog.DataSource = accountsForToComboBox;
```

You need to populate those initial variables without referencing the same object.

I have no idea what `AccountCollection` looks like internally, so I'm not sure I can recommend how to populate each of your variables from `Customer.Accounts`.

If it's just a list, you should be able to use:

```
var accountsForFromComboBox = new AccountCollection(Customer.Accounts);
var accountsForToComboBox = new AccountCollection(Customer.Accounts);
```

Comment: Hi Grant! AccountCollection is List<Accounts>